# PostgreSQL Querying timestamp without timezone returns different results

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Why does these queries return different results?

**Query A.1**

```
select 
    p.name
from properties p
where p.timestamp_gmt between '2018-08-06' and '2018-08-07';
```

**Query A.2**

```
select 
    p.name
from properties p
where p.timestamp_gmt between DATE '2018-08-06' and DATE '2018-08-07';
```

These two queries return 100 records and take less than a second.

**Query B**

```
select 
    p.name
from properties p
where p.timestamp_gmt >= 'Thu Sep 06 2018' and p.timestamp_gmt < 'Fri Sep 07 2018';
```

This query returns 10000 records and takes 30 min.

Notice that the only difference here is the date comparison operator, which is `>=` and `<`. I don't understand what's the right way of querying a `timestamp without time zone`

Should results be the same? Are **A** and **B** queries fundamentally different?

Comment: Note that the date range in the query B `WHERE` clause is not the same as the range used in the first two A queries.  I'd like to see the execution plan of all three queries, and I'll bet that would partially explain the running times you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, typo, let me edit...

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`?

Comment: **1)** `September <> August`  **2)** `BETWEEN` is inclusive at both sides.

Comment: @wildplasser not sure what you mean in 1)